# private register variable | OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Consider,

```
register int a;
```

Does program allocate private register variables to each thread at the clause,

```
#pragma omp parallel private(a)
```

Or private automatic variables ?

Answer (score 0):

The `register` keyword is not what its name implies, it is just an automatic variable for which you wouldn't be allowed to apply the address-of operator `&`. Therefore OpenMp shouldn't treat such a variable different from variables that are explicitly or implicitly declared `auto`.

Comment: Thank you @Jens. But my program runs much faster when I add the register keyword.

Comment: Sounds interesting, perhaps your compiler takes this as an additional hint, but doesn't change anything to my answer.